# Self teaching "Curiculum"

Tags: soft-question, self-learning

This will probably be flagged but here goes anyway.

I guess I am a glutton for punishment, but, I have been trying to self teach advanced math ever since I realized that if I want to read anything of consequence in science I will need to understand advanced math. So far, having left off with alg. II in high school, I'm reasonable at Trig, I have a good grasp of differentiation and integration techniques up to trigonometric substitution.I can handle Calc 2 but I wouldn't say I am any better than a C-equivalent student right now, and I am still trying to translate $\Sigma$ and $\Pi$ notations.. so I guess that is where I am at.

So I am wondering, what would be a good roadmap of OpenCourseWare and other self teaching resource topics to get me from basic Calc to "the great beyond".

Thanks in advance

Comment: That depends on what you are interested in. If you want to do all kinds of science, you need to learn basically everything. So the question is: what scientific (field) questions do you want to be able to answer? Of course you need proper knowledge of linear algebra and of calculus but depending on what you are interested in you will rather need measure theory and lots of probability or rather differential geometry and lots of functional analysis.

Comment: Have a look at Thomas's calculus https://duckduckgo.com/?q=thomas%27s+calculus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advise is to study what you need when you need it. That way you won't waste time studying stuff you won't use, and having a real-world application at hand is normally wonderful to check your understanding against, and helps motivate problems and techniques in the field. On the other hand, if some area interests you "just for the fun of it," just go right ahead! Have sites like this one at hand to get over rough spots.